# SQL Calculating Turn-Around-Time with Overlapping Concideration

Tags: sql, overlapping

I have a Table (parts) where I store when an item was requested and when it was issued. With this, I can easily compute each items turn-around-time ("TAT").  What I'd like to do is have another column ("Computed") where any overlapping request-to-issue dates are properly computed.

```
RecID   Requested   Issued       TAT   Computed
MD0001  11/28/2012  12/04/2012   6.00    0.00
MD0002  11/28/2012  11/28/2012   0.00    0.00
MD0003  11/28/2012  12/04/2012   6.00    0.00
MD0004  11/28/2012  11/28/2012   0.00    0.00
MD0005  11/28/2012  12/10/2012  12.00    0.00
MD0006  11/28/2012  01/21/2013  54.00   54.00
MD0007  11/28/2012  11/28/2012   0.00    0.00
MD0008  11/28/2012  12/04/2012   6.00    0.00
MD0009  01/29/2013  01/30/2013   1.00    1.00
MD0010  01/29/2013  01/30/2013   1.00    0.00
MD0011  02/05/2013  02/06/2013   1.00    1.00
MD0012  02/07/2013  03/04/2013  25.00   25.00
MD0013  03/07/2013  03/14/2013   7.00    7.00
MD0014  03/07/2013  03/08/2013   1.00    0.00
MD0015  03/13/2013  03/25/2013  12.00   11.00
MD0016  03/20/2013  03/21/2013   1.00    0.00
                       Totals  133.00   99.00 <- waiting for parts TAT summary
```

In the above, I manually filled in the ("Computed") column so that there is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

NOTE: Notice how MD0013 affects the computed time for MD0015 as MD0013 was "computed" first. This could have been where MD0015 was computed first, then MD0013 would be affected accordingly - the net result is there is -1 day.

Comment: I do not understand the overlapping logic.  Could you elaborate further?

Comment: MD0001 thru MD0005 and MD0007 and MD0008 were "Issued" while MD0006 was still waiting to be "Issued", so the "computed" TAT for these RecID's shouldn't count (aka: 0).

Comment: I'll add that this table is "detail" data to a parent record and the parent record has a received_date and completed_date.

Comment: "*MD0001 thru MD0005 and MD0007 and MD0008 were "Issued" while MD0006 was still waiting to be "Issued", so the "computed" TAT for these RecID's shouldn't count (aka: 0).*"  How did you determine it based on your table? What is the **exact** logic for `Computed` field.

Comment: Their "wait times" (aka: Request-to-Issue datetime) is encapsulated/covered by the "wait time" (aka: Request-to-Issue datetime) of MD0006, so the "computed" TAT is 0 for those items.